# xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'

Tags: selenium, applet, appium, xcuitest

Hello I am having issues in launching ios real device for testing.

My xcode version: 11.2.1 (11B500)
Appium Version : 1.13.0 (1.13.0.20190505.6)

These are my capabilities:

```
    deviceSerialNumber:         F71SVVQ2HG7F
[Xcode]         identifier:                 bfda036179b938524f01eff8c673de3388a07fcc
[Xcode]         deviceClass:                iPhone
[Xcode]         deviceName:                 iPhone 7
[Xcode]         deviceIdentifier:           bfda036179b938524f01eff8c673de3388a07fcc
[Xcode]         productVersion:             13.1.1
[Xcode]         buildVersion:               17A854
[Xcode]         deviceSoftwareVersion:      13.1.1 (17A854)
[Xcode]         deviceArchitecture:         arm64
[Xcode]         deviceTotalCapacity:        26495004672
[Xcode]         deviceAvailableCapacity:    9949319168
[Xcode]         deviceIsTransient:          NO
[Xcode]         ignored:                    NO
[Xcode]         deviceIsBusy:               NO
[Xcode]         deviceIsPaired:             YES
[Xcode]         deviceIsActivated:          YES
[Xcode]         deviceActivationState:      Activated
[Xcode]         isPasscodeLocked:           NO
[Xcode]         deviceType:                 
[Xcode]         supportedDeviceFamilies:    (
[Xcode]     1
[Xcode] )
[Xcode]         applications:              (null)
[Xcode]         provisioningProfiles:      (null)
[Xcode]         hasInternalSupport:        NO
[Xcode]         hasWritableSystem:         NO
[Xcode]         isSupportedOS:             YES
[Xcode]         bootArgs:                  (null)
[Xcode]         nextBootArgs:              (null)
[Xcode]         connected:                 YES
[Xcode]         isWirelessEnabled:         NO
[Xcode]         connectionType:            direct
[Xcode]         hostname:                  iPhone-7.local.
[Xcode]         bonjourServiceName:        d0:c5:f3:d7:01:46@fe80::d2c5:f3ff:fed7:146._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.
[Xcode]         activeProxiedDevice:       (null)
[Xcode]         } (13.1.1 (17A854))
```

This says xcode needs provisioning profile whereas I have set the certificates and profiles in the xode...

```
[Xcode] Testing failed:
[Xcode]     "WebDriverAgentRunner" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
[Xcode]     No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "BNL4VQ2576" with a private key was found.
[Xcode]     WebDriverAgentRunner:
[Xcode]         WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app encountered an error (Failed to install or launch the test runner. (Underlying error: The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. The file doesn’t exist. (Underlying error: The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory)))




[Xcode] ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED **
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] Testing started on 'iPhone 7'
[Xcode] 
[XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
[XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
[XCUITest] Carthage found: '/usr/local/bin/carthage'
[XCUITest] Killing running processes 'xcodebuild.*bfda036179b938524f01eff8c673de3388a07fcc, iproxy 8100' for the device bfda036179b938524f01eff8c673de3388a07fcc...
[XCUITest] 'pgrep -nif xcodebuild.*bfda036179b938524f01eff8c673de3388a07fcc' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
```

This says the folder is not present. I manually opened the directory and there is no folder there. I don't know how to get that folder.

```
[Xcode] 2019-11-22 16:17:12.722 xcodebuild[37042:259128] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/ahmsam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdfc6b5e4c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to setup WDA by following Full Manual configuration in the [documentation](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md)
   (If you skipped any of the steps, WDA won't work)
2. Update the product bundle identifier with the custom one you added  `com.companyName.WebDriverAgentRunner`
3. open WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj from `/path/where/installed/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent` in Xcode
4. Project -> Build

Comment: my xcode project is not in this path /path/where/installed/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent..  Where as it is located at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent

Comment: That is the location for appium installed via terminal. Are you trying to run tests using appium desktop or terminal?

Comment: I'm running through appium desktop.

Comment: (from the root, not from the userName) /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent there is .xcodeproj that you need to sign.

Comment: I have got this appuim desktop location now.. so i have to sign in for webdriveragentlib and webdriveragentrunner targets???

Comment: If you can build the webdriveragent onto the targeted device , it may resolve the issue. But you will need to sign in.

Comment: I did follow the manual configuration. WHen I build WebDriverAgentLib it builds successfully but the app does not installs on the device, Why is that so? but when I run this command on terminal. Then webdriveragent app installs.  "xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=bfda036179b938524f01eff8c673de3388a07fcc' test ". But still my session doesnot start and gives error with code 65 ,

Comment: can you give your contact? I'm still stucked,

Answer (score 0):

in my case i fixed this with following in appium 2.0, xcode 14

- Closed all xcode projects and restart the WDA and rebuilt
- start appium with >> appium --allow-cors
- in Appium inspector set :
  Remote host - 0.0.0.0
  Remote Port - 4723 and Remote Path - / ( only /)
  Checked in allow unauthorized certificates
  and added capabilites
  "appium:path": "/",
  "showXcodeLog": true

i hope this will work.